# Jquery button not firing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button made using href like so:

```
 <div id='swipebuttons'>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-success" id='swiperightbtn'>Swipe right (yes)</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" id='swipeleftbtn'>Swipe left (no)</a>
 <div>
```

And jquery backend like so:

```
$('#swiperightbtn').on("click",function() {
    document.write('yes');
});
```

I am using document.write just to test that it is actually working. However, when I load this nothing happens, along with no reports in the log/developer console.

Comment: try use alert('yes').

Comment: You've included your script file in your html yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
  $('#swiperightbtn, #swipeleftbtn').on("click",function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('yes');
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div id='swipebuttons'>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-success" id='swiperightbtn'>Swipe right (yes)</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" id='swipeleftbtn'>Swipe left (no)</a>
  <div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/37am9/1/

Or you can use the selector `$('#swipebuttons a')`

Comment: One of his IDs is swipeRIGHT the other is swipeLEFT

Comment: @Deryck, Sorry I was over looked, Thanks. i have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $('#swiperightbtn').on("click",function() {
        document.write('yes');
        return false;
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: It'll still try to change to an empty page with this

Answer (score 0):

Gotta keep the anchor from thinking it has another job to do.

```
$('#swiperightbtn').on("click",function() {
    document.write('yes');
    return false;
});
```

### [Example working](http://jsfiddle.net/TTGPV/)

If you don't `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` the link will try to continue to the empty `href=""`.